# How to fix 'Expected n parameters' in a vba select query

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I had an existing vba query that I modified to return a few extra fields. Now, when opening a recordset of this query, I get an exception that notifies me that the query is missing parameter:

> Run-time error '3061': Too few parameters. Expected 3.

Somehow the newly added fields are being seen as parameters.

When I open this query in access, the new fields are returned in the record. I've tried removing one of the new fields and then noticed that the amount of missing parameters did go down. There is no place where I marked this query as having parameters.

```vb
Dim query As String

query = "SELECT DATA, NAME, LOCATION, NEWFIELD1, NEWFIELD2, NEWFIELD3, NEWFIELD4 FROM qryAccesQuery WHERE NAME='FOOBAR';"

Dim qdef As QueryDef
Set qdef = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("newQuery", query)

Dim rs As RecordSet
Set rs = qdef.OpenRecordSet ' Run-time error '3061': Too few parameters. Expected 3.
```

The problem/solution might be pretty obvious, but I am fairly new to vba development.

Comment: If you are getting fields from query `qryAccesQuery`, maybe the parameters are there? Do those new fields exists in `qryAccesQuery`?

Comment: Just ound out that some legacy code is overwriting the existing query everytime so My changes had no effect. Thank you or the comment however

Comment: Please consider deleting this question, since the problem obviously can't be solved with only the information in the question, as per your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was some legacy code overwriting the existing query.

I performed a search over the entire module for that queryName, and very quickly i found out that the query is also stored in a database somewhere and is reset to the database version everytime it is called.

The lesson I learned today is that you need to search through the entire application and not assume anything when working with legacy code.